# How to convert from ASCII to Hex and vice versa?

Tags: c

I need to convert `ASCII` to `HEX` and `HEX` to `ASCII` by using a C program.
How can I do that?

Comment: You mean ascii characters to hex eg "A" -> "0x41"? Or evaluate the string "0x41"? And how far have you got so far?

Comment: ASCII is a character set and encoding, i.e. a bijective mapping between the integers in [0, 127] to characters. The integers can either be expressed in decimal (e.g. 100) or in hexadecimal (e.g. 0x64). Hence, it makes no sense to convert between ASCII and hexadecimal. Either you are interested in finding the integer corresponding to a character, or you are interested in converting an integer between different bases.

Comment: It will be good if you paste your code here after reading the links/tips/pseudo-code/code written below inorder to achieve your final goal.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a simplistic function to convert one character to a hexadecimal string.

```
char hexDigit(unsigned n)
{
    if (n < 10) {
        return n + '0';
    } else {
        return (n - 10) + 'A';
    }
}

void charToHex(char c, char hex[3])
{
    hex[0] = hexDigit(c / 0x10);
    hex[1] = hexDigit(c % 0x10);
    hex[2] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Note that the C standard doesn't guarantee that the values of the letters are contiguous.  (It does make that guarantee for digits.)  Simpler: `"0123456789ABCDEF"[n]`.

Answer (score 2):

Its pretty easy.  Scan through character by character ... best to start from the end.  If the character is a number between 0 and 9 or a letter between a and f then place it in the correct position by left shifting it by the number of digits you've found so far.

For converting to a string then you do similar but first you mask and right shift the values.  You then convert them to the character and place them in the string.