# Store hex equivalent of character in C

Tags: c, hex, ascii

Referring second answer to question: [How to convert from ASCII to Hex and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212848/how-to-convert-from-ascii-to-hex-and-vice-versa)

I want to save the char hex[3] equivalent of different characters as follows:

```
char *str ="abcd";

// I want to get hex[3] of each character in above string and save into the following:

char str2[4]; // should contain hex values as : \x61 for a,\x62 for b,\x63 for c,\x64 for d
```

How can I do this ?

I tried the following so far:

```
int i;
char ch;
char hex[3];
for(i=0; i<strlen(str);i++) {
    ch = charToHex(*(str+i), hex);
    // now hex contains the first and second hex characters in hex[0] & hex[1]
    // I need to save them in the first index of str2 
    // e.g. if hex[0] = 7 and hex[1] = f, then str2[0] should be "\x7f"

    // -> how do I do this part ?

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: This isn't a write-my-code-for-me site. What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Also note that the string `"\\x61"` probably doesn't fit into a `char[4]` because of the null-terminator. (I say "probably", because you can work without null-terminators if you want, but it's awkward, and, I suspect, not what you intended.)

Comment: Answers don't appear in a fixed order -- the order depends on upvotes and downvotes -- so "second answer" is not a useful description of what you're referring to. Why not link directly to the answer you have in mind, using the "link" link at the bottom of it?

Comment: @Jake: `str2[0]` is of type `char`. It can't hold the string `"\\x7f"`. If you want to store the value `0x7f` as a character, then you are doing nothing more than copying the source data unmodified, in which case you may as well just write `memcpy(str2, str, 4)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`for` loop](http://cprogramminglanguage.net/c-for-loop-statement.aspx) to iterate over all characters of a string, and then apply the conversion for each character. Bear in mind that C strings are [null-terminated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string).

Also note that 4 characters will not be enough if you want to store `\x61\x62\x63\x64` - you'll need `4 * strlen(str) + 1`, i.e. 17.

---

In response to the code:

You don't actually need `ch`. The [function `charToHex`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3212885/35070) return `void`, i.e. nothing.

Simply copy the characters to the output string, like this:

```
str2[2*i] = hex[0];
str2[2*i+1] = hex[1];
```

Again, don't forget to set the null terminator in the result string.

Also, since you call `strlen` in each iteration, you're writing a [Schlemiel the Painter algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter's_algorithm).

Comment: I tried your solution; at the end when str2 is printed using printf("%s",str2), it prints out 61626364.

Now my question is that is I have : char *str3="\x61\x62\x63\x64", is this the same as the result we got, because objective is to convert from str1 to str3 format.

Comment: Well, if you want an additional `\x`, you can simply set every fourth character to `'\\'`, and every fourth character (starting with the second) to `'x'`. The code stays the same; just replace `2*i` with `4*i`.

Comment: Will there be any change in size ?

Comment: I recommend not thinking in terms of *change*, but simply determining the size. If you have *x* characters in the output for every input character, you'll need to reserve `x * strlen(input) + 1` bytes in the output.