# Reading from a file as a hexadecimal value

Tags: c++, c, file, hex

I have a simple text file and i want to read it as hexadecimal. For example following text is in text file "315c4e", now these are actually three bytes, i want to save them in separate variables(or in an array, which ever is possible). For example, the first variable say uint8_t v1, should contain 31, in other words this variable should have 00110001 value(which is 31 in hex).

I am doing a cryptography assignment in my college and i had to read values from text files which contain hex-encoded cipher texts.

Comment: If your text file contains "315c4e" then that is 6 ascii characters. You want to convert ascii to hex, then look for e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212848/how-to-convert-from-ascii-to-hex-and-vice-versa

Comment: If you're reading a file that, if printed, would display hex data, then read the file as character data and convert the characters using a hex-to-binary algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

The normal `setw` and `setprecision` won't limit the amount of input read to two characters, so something like this:

```
infile >> std::setw(2) >> setprecision(2) >> std::hex >> ch;
```

...just won't work. That being the case, it's probably about as easy as anything to just read a 2-character string, and do the conversion yourself:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctype.h>

unsigned char hstouc(std::string const &in) {
    static const std::string v{ "0123456789ABCDEF" };

    return v.find(toupper(in[0])) * 16 + v.find(toupper(in[1]));
} 

int main() {
    std::istringstream in{ "315c4e" };

    std::vector<unsigned char> vals;

    std::string temp;

    while (in >> std::setw(2) >> temp)
        vals.push_back(hstouc(temp));

    for (unsigned v : vals)
        std::cout << v << "\t";
}
```

If your input is machine generated, that will probably suffice. If it may have been edited by hand (or anything else that could produce incorrect input) you'll probably need/want to add some error checking to the conversion routine. Alternatively, you might want to use something like `strtoul`, which already does such checking, then cast the result to `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 0):

This question gave me the idea to the following function and I can't resist to post it here. BTW, is there a standard function doing the same as this `atob`?

```
int atob(unsigned char c) {
    static char     x[256];
    int             i;
    if (x[0]==0) {
        for(i=0;i<256;i++) x[i] = -1; 
        for(i=0;i<10;i++) x[i+'0'] = i;
        for(i=0;i<6;i++) x[i+'a']= x[i+'A'] = i+10;
    }
    return(x[c]);
}

int main() {
    FILE    *ff;
    int     hex, c1, c2;

    ff = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    for(;;) {
        c1 = fgetc(ff);
        c2 = fgetc(ff);
        if (c2 == EOF) break;
        hex = atob(c1)*16 + atob(c2);
        printf("0x%02x ", hex);
    }
    fclose(ff);
}
```

Comment: You could copy the 2 chars into a null-terminated char[3] buffer and `sscanf(buf,"%x",...);` on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read tuples of 3 bytes (6 characters) separated by white spaces:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

struct ToHex
{
    typedef std::uint8_t byte;
    typedef std::istream::traits_type traits;
    byte& value;

    ToHex(byte& value)
    : value(value)
    {}

    void read(std::istream& stream) const {
        byte b[2];
        for(unsigned i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
            traits::char_type ch = stream.get();
            if('0' <= ch && ch <= '9') b[i] = ch - '0';
            else if('a' <= ch && ch <= 'f') b[i] = ch - 'a' + 10;
            else if('A' <= ch && ch <= 'F') b[i] = ch - 'A' + 10;
            else {
                if(ch != traits::eof())
                    stream.putback(ch);
                stream.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
            }
        }
        value = b[0] * 16 + b[1]; // Rubbish if an extraction failed
    }
};

inline ToHex to_hex(ToHex::byte& value) {
    return ToHex(value);
}

inline std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& stream, const ToHex& value) {
    value.read(stream);
    return stream;
}

int main() {
    std::istringstream input(""
        "315c4e\n"
        "010c0e\n"
        "Failure");

    ToHex::byte a[3];
    input >> std::ws;
    while(input && ! input.eof()) {
        for(unsigned i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
            input >> to_hex(a[i]);
        }
        if(input) {
            for(unsigned i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
                std::cout << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << (unsigned)a[i];
            std::cout  << '\n';
            input >> std::ws;
        }
    }
    if(input.fail()) {
        std::cerr << "Failure\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: "315c4e" is just for an example, the input file may contain many more characters.

Comment: @KhurramShehzad Thats why I added "010c0e" and "Failure" to the input